# An attached callback during children.clear in parent's detached callback

Tags: dart, web-component, dart-html

Simple scenario: have 2 web components, *child* inside *parent*. 
When reinserting *parent* to smth else place, **detached** callback has been called of *parent*, and children.clear() invokes in it (maybe it is silly place here).
During clearing of children I can see that not only *child's* **detached** cb called, but **attached** too:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/26921310fb7f85dee672

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {

  document.registerElement("x-my", MyElement);
  document.registerElement("x-ch", MyChild);
  var container = new Element.tag("x-my");
  document.body.children.add( container );
  print("creation done");

  // just re-add container to somewhere else
  var anothercontainer = new Element.div();
  document.body.children.add( anothercontainer );
  anothercontainer.children.add(container);

}

class MyElement extends HtmlElement {
  MyElement.created() : super.created();

  @override
  attached() {
    print("attached enter ${this.outerHtml}");
    super.attached();
    children.add( new Element.tag("x-ch") );
    print("attached leave ${this.outerHtml}");
  }

   @override
  detached() {
    print("detached enter ${this.outerHtml}");
    children.clear();
    super.detached();
    print("detached leave ${this.outerHtml}");
  }
}

class MyChild extends HtmlElement {
  MyChild.created() : super.created() { this.innerHtml = "child created"; }

  @override
  attached() {
    print("attached enter ${this.outerHtml}");
    super.attached();
    print("attached leave ${this.outerHtml}");
  }

   @override
  detached() {
    print("detached enter ${this.outerHtml}");
    super.detached();
    print("detached leave ${this.outerHtml}");
  }
}
```

Gives output:

```
attached enter <x-my></x-my>
attached enter <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
attached leave <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
attached leave <x-my><x-ch>child created</x-ch></x-my>
creation done
detached enter <x-my><x-ch>child created</x-ch></x-my>
detached enter <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
detached leave <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
attached enter <x-ch>child created</x-ch> <---- my question
attached leave <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
detached enter <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
detached leave <x-ch>child created</x-ch> <---- ends here
detached leave <x-my></x-my>
attached enter <x-my></x-my>
attached enter <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
attached leave <x-ch>child created</x-ch>
attached leave <x-my><x-ch>child created</x-ch></x-my>
```

Comment: such behavior in Chrome 48.0.2564.97.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue about this AFAIR. I think it's caused by modifying the DOM from within the constructor of a custom element.

Try to move

```
 this.innerHtml = "child created";
```

to `attached()`

Comment: but ctor doesn't called while reattaching element, isn't it?